# Gmail HTML app on Launcher feedback

Tags: gmail, html

I'm on the ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed Gmail in the HTML app launchable from laucher. I need help where I can send my feedback about this app, because in stock ubuntu touch browser gmail and every other app seems to lag when clicking on link (which opens in Chrome) and stop working after clicking the link.

I need more information about where and to whom I can contact to make this work better.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the app in the software center, and you will be able to write a review of it there.  Also, [this](http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/)  may be helpful because it is a Google product.